# My android app crash when installed in android 4.4.2

Tags: android, sdk, build.gradle

I am trying to test my android application in my device.
First i have tested on `android 6` and it works fine, when i try to installed in my android `4.4.2` device it crashed.
This is the sdk information in my gradle file

```
 compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
  minSdkVersion 14
  targetSdkVersion 25
```

Any one here have any idea can help me please.
Logcat:
`02-22 12:46:17.170 2136-2136/? D/dalvikvm: Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
02-22 12:46:17.190 2136-2136/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-22 12:46:17.190 2136-2136/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x9cd8eb20)
02-22 12:46:17.190 2136-2142/? E/jdwp: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
02-22 12:46:17.190 2136-2142/? D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-22 12:46:17.190 2136-2136/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.kaouther.needtaxi, PID: 2136
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.kaouther.needtaxi-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.kaouther.needtaxi-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4793)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.kaouther.needtaxi-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.kaouther.needtaxi-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
02-22 12:47:36.370 2136-2136/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2136 SIG: 9`

Comment: Could you post the log cat after the crash

Comment: post your error log!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big reason (on lower version android devices) of this issue is adding Play Services dependency. Avoid adding whole Play services gradle dependency. Instead of whole Play Services dependency, add only specific dependency which you going to use in your project (such as : location, maps, places etc.).

Also enable Multidex by doing below steps :

1. In Build.gradle(Module:app)
   'defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.***.****"
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 25
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       multiDexEnabled true
   }'
2. add insert into dependencies :
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
3. Then add code to manifest :
    
   android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

Hope. It would work.

Comment: i will try it, can you please check logcat i have update the question

Comment: Thaaaaanks you save my day :D. i have replaced : compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0' with compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0' and it works